# PDF to Json using PDFX Python library

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, parsing, pdf

I am trying to convert .PDF's to JSON files in order to scrape the information out of them easier.  I can get the metadata from the .PDF file, but it only has the first page or what looks to be the parameters for the .PDF but it doesn't list the actual data.  Below is my code.  It is very simple as I am still learning how to use the library and this is what I was able to get from the documentation on the library's site.

```
import pdfx

pdf = pdfx.PDFx("Q1_Employee_Earnings_Record.pdf")
metadata = pdf.get_metadata()
reference_list = pdf.get_references()
reference_dict = pdf.get_references_as_dict()
pdf.download_pdfs("target-directory")
```

Here is my output:

```
{
  "source": {
    "type": "file",
    "location": "Q1_Employee_Earnings_Record.pdf",
    "filename": "Q1_Employee_Earnings_Record.pdf"
  },
  "metadata": {
    "Creator": "HP Exstream Version 8.0.317 64-bit",
    "CreationDate": "3/31/2017 21:51:48",
    "Author": "Registered to: PAYCHEX ",
    "Title": "Employee Earnings Record Application",
    "Pages": 26
  },
  "references": {}
}
```

As you can see there are 26 pages, but the pages and the information contained within will not output.  Is there a way to get my code above to output all of the data from every page?  I know the data is accessible since I have converted this exact .PDF into a text file using PDFminer.

Answer (score 0):

From a scan of the [source code](https://github.com/metachris/pdfx/blob/master/pdfx/__init__.py), it looks like you can just call `pdf.get_text()`.

The focus of the library seems to be on the metadata. Other PDF libraries might give you more fine-grained access to the text if getting it all as one string isn't enough.

Comment: Thanks.  Getting it all in one string is not enough at this point.  I was using PDFminer to get a text file since the formatting was what i needed, but using a library lets me control when the documents are converted.  I cannot seem to find a reliable library that does this unfortunately.